# Select closest neighbor with specific property

Tags: neo4j

The question may seem a little naive, but is it possible to select the nearest vertex of a tree with a specific value of property? For example, let's create

```
CREATE (a: IM { level:0 })-[:conn { weight: 1 }]->(fchild1:task { completed:false })
CREATE (a)-[:conn { weight: 1 }]->(fchild2:task { completed:true })
CREATE (fchild1)-[:conn { weight: 1 }]->(b:task { completed:false })
CREATE (fchild1)-[:conn { weight: 1 }]->(c:task { completed:true })
CREATE (fchild1)-[:conn { weight: 1 }]->(d:task { completed:false })
CREATE (fchild2)-[:conn { weight: 1 }]->(e:task { completed:false })
CREATE (fchild2)-[:conn { weight: 1 }]->(f:task { completed:false })
```

Is it possible to select the the nearest node for `c` which has completed=false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to go both up and down the tree?  Either way it shouldn't be too hard:

```
MATCH path, (a:IM)-[*1..10]-(other:IM)
WHERE <some match to get your `a` node> AND other.completed = false
RETURN other, length(path) AS distance
ORDER BY length(path)
LIMIT 1
```

You can increase the `10` or remove the `1..10` as you see fit.  Depending on your graph this may greatly increase your query time.